# Is it possible to extract installed TeXlive from one computer in-order to install it (TeXlive) on another computer?

Tags: texlive

Assuming I install TeXlive 2015 on laptop A using an online installation, is it possible to install TeXlive 2015 on another laptop say laptop B by extracting (or copying) 'something' from laptop A, copy the 'something' to flash-drive and use the copied 'something' to install TeXlive 2015 on laptop B IF direct download of TeXlive 2015 ISO file is not working. This I think will help in saving financial obligation involved twice (or for the number of fresh TeXlive 2015 installation(s)). Please accommodate my ignorance, if my question is not good.
Thank you.

Comment: What financial obligation? Texlive can be installed in a portable configuration and then replicated where-ever you like.

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn thank you, What I mean by 'financial obligation' is expenses on internet air time. How can it be replicated?

Comment: I think the easiest to to might be to rsync the tlnet folder from one of the ctan mirrors that provide rsync support. Then put that folder on a USB and install from it. That is what we do for install parties (when downloading over the wireless becomes cumbersome because too many people are doing the same at the same time.

Comment: Also it *is* possible to transplant tl from one windows to another. I gave a script that can do that, though it has never seen wide use.

Answer (score 2):

TeX Live installations are essentially self-contained. Assuming you go with the standard ['vanilla' installation from TUG](http://tug.org/texlive/), you will have

- Windows: `C:\texlive\<year>`
- Linux/Mac: `/usr/local/texlive/<year>`

This entire directory can then be copied from one machine to another, and it is then only a question of pointing whatever tool(s) you use to do TeX editing to the system. At the minimum, I would add the system to the path, which will depend on the OS and is really edge-of-scope for us.

Comment: thank you but how can I point TeX editor such as Emacs-AUCTeX to the system on Windows or Mac?